# Finite element method: what are bilinear and linear forms?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, finite-element-method

## Sample problem

Consider this ODE:

$$ u : \Omega \to \Re $$
$$\nabla u-u=0 \qquad \mathrm{in} \qquad \Omega$$
$$\Omega\subset\Re$$
$$ u = 1 \qquad \mathrm{on} \qquad \Gamma$$

- $\Omega\subset\Re$ is the domain of interest where $0\le x \le 1$
- $\Gamma$ is domain's boundary where $x=0$
- $\nabla u-u=0$ would become $\frac{du}{dx}-u=0$

## Finite element as I know it

I would solve it by using the finite element method. First, I assume the solution to be a polynomial which satisfies the boundary condition:

$$ u := \begin{bmatrix} 1 & x & x^2 & x^3 & x^4 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix}$$

So, the equation $\frac{du}{dx}-u=0$ would become:

$$ \frac{d}{dx}(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & x & x^2 & x^3 & x^4 \end{bmatrix}) \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 1 & x & x^2 & x^3 & x^4 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix} = 0$$

I multiply both sides of the question by transpose of $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & x & x^2 & x^3 & x^4 \end{bmatrix}$ like:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ x \\ x^2 \\ x^3 \\ x^4 \end{bmatrix} \left( \frac{d}{dx}(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & x & x^2 & x^3 & x^4 \end{bmatrix}) \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 1 & x & x^2 & x^3 & x^4 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix} = 0 \right)$$

The equation would become:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ x \\ x^2 \\ x^3 \\ x^4 \end{bmatrix} \frac{d}{dx}(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & x & x^2 & x^3 & x^4 \end{bmatrix}) \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ x \\ x^2 \\ x^3 \\ x^4 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & x & x^2 & x^3 & x^4 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

The equation would be:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ x \\ x^2 \\ x^3 \\ x^4 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2x & 3x^2 & 4x^3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ x \\ x^2 \\ x^3 \\ x^4 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & x & x^2 & x^3 & x^4 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

The equation would be:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2x & 3x^2 & 4x^3 \\ 0 & x & 2x^2 & 3x^3 & 4x^4 \\ 0 & x^2 & 2x^3 & 3x^4 & 4x^5 \\ 0 & x^3 & 2x^4 & 3x^5 & 4x^6 \\ 0 & x^4 & 2x^5 & 3x^6 & 4x^7 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 1 & x & x^2 & x^3 & x^4 \\ x & x^2 & x^3 & x^4 & x^5 \\ x^2 & x^3 & x^4 & x^5 & x^6 \\ x^3 & x^4 & x^5 & x^6 & x^7 \\ x^4 & x^5 & x^6 & x^7 & x^8 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

Now we do the integral of both sides of the equation over the $\Omega$ domain:

$$ \int_0^1 \left( \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2x & 3x^2 & 4x^3 \\ 0 & x & 2x^2 & 3x^3 & 4x^4 \\ 0 & x^2 & 2x^3 & 3x^4 & 4x^5 \\ 0 & x^3 & 2x^4 & 3x^5 & 4x^6 \\ 0 & x^4 & 2x^5 & 3x^6 & 4x^7 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 1 & x & x^2 & x^3 & x^4 \\ x & x^2 & x^3 & x^4 & x^5 \\ x^2 & x^3 & x^4 & x^5 & x^6 \\ x^3 & x^4 & x^5 & x^6 & x^7 \\ x^4 & x^5 & x^6 & x^7 & x^8 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \right) \mathrm{d}x$$

The equation would be:

$$ \int_0^1 \left( \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2x & 3x^2 & 4x^3 \\ 0 & x & 2x^2 & 3x^3 & 4x^4 \\ 0 & x^2 & 2x^3 & 3x^4 & 4x^5 \\ 0 & x^3 & 2x^4 & 3x^5 & 4x^6 \\ 0 & x^4 & 2x^5 & 3x^6 & 4x^7 \end{bmatrix} \right) \mathrm{d}x \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix} - \int_0^1 \left( \begin{bmatrix} 1 & x & x^2 & x^3 & x^4 \\ x & x^2 & x^3 & x^4 & x^5 \\ x^2 & x^3 & x^4 & x^5 & x^6 \\ x^3 & x^4 & x^5 & x^6 & x^7 \\ x^4 & x^5 & x^6 & x^7 & x^8 \end{bmatrix} \right) \mathrm{d}x \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

Having computed the integrals, the equation would be:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{3}{4} & \frac{4}{5} \\ 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{3}{5} & \frac{2}{3} \\ 0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{4}{7} \\ 0 & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{3}{7} & \frac{1}{2} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{5} \\ \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{6} \\ \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{7} \\ \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{8} \\ \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{9} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

Having done the subtraction, the equation would be:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} -1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{3}{4} & \frac{4}{5} \\ \frac{-1}{2} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{5}{12} & \frac{11}{20} & \frac{19}{30} \\ \frac{-1}{3} & \frac{1}{12} & \frac{3}{10} & \frac{13}{30} & \frac{11}{21} \\ \frac{-1}{4} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{7}{30} & \frac{5}{14} & \frac{25}{56} \\ \frac{-1}{5} & \frac{1}{30} & \frac{4}{21} & \frac{17}{56} & \frac{7}{18} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

Getting rid of the first row, the equation would become:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \frac{-1}{2} \\ \frac{-1}{3} \\ \frac{-1}{4} \\ \frac{-1}{5} \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{6} & \frac{5}{12} & \frac{11}{20} & \frac{19}{30} \\ \frac{1}{12} & \frac{3}{10} & \frac{13}{30} & \frac{11}{21} \\ \frac{1}{20} & \frac{7}{30} & \frac{5}{14} & \frac{25}{56} \\ \frac{1}{30} & \frac{4}{21} & \frac{17}{56} & \frac{7}{18} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

The solution of the above linear algebra problem would be:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1704}{1709} \\ \frac{882}{1709} \\ \frac{224}{1709} \\ \frac{126}{1709} \end{bmatrix} $$

The 1st row which we got rid of giving:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} -1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{3}{4} & \frac{4}{5} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{3}{4} & \frac{4}{5} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \frac{1704}{1709} \\ \frac{882}{1709} \\ \frac{224}{1709} \\ \frac{126}{1709} \end{bmatrix} = \frac{-1}{8545} = -0.000117 \approx 0 $$

Comparison with the exact solution $e^x$ is done:

| x | $e^x$ | FEM approximation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0.1 | 1.10517 | 1.10501 |
| 0.2 | 1.2214 | 1.22123 |
| 0.3 | 1.34986 | 1.34971 |
| 0.4 | 1.49182 | 1.49168 |
| 0.5 | 1.64872 | 1.64855 |
| 0.6 | 1.82212 | 1.8219 |
| 0.7 | 2.01375 | 2.0135 |
| 0.8 | 2.22554 | 2.22526 |
| 0.9 | 2.4596 | 2.45932 |
| 1.0 | 2.71828 | 2.71796 |

## Is my understanding correct?

### My first question

Is my finite element method of solving the above ODE correct? Is it thorough?

## Bilinear form and linear form

### my second question

I'm studying this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.09220.pdf

It contains this explanation about its *Finite Element Abstractions*:

[image: Ppaer screenshot: Finite Element Abstractions]

I'm trying to find a correspondence between paper equations (3), (4), (5), and (6) and my finite element understanding. The paper is talking about bilinear and linear forms. I'm trying to figure out the corresponding **bilinear** and **linear** forms inside my finite element solution described above. I'm trying to wrap my head around the paper equations with my limited knowledge of the finite element method. I'd appreciate any help or hint that would make me understand the paper.

Comment: Specifically, the paper's equation (3), on the left-hand side replaces the Laplace operator of $\nabla$ with $\Delta \cdot \Delta$ which makes sense. However, only the right-hand side is multiplied by $v_h$ which isn't consistent with the left-hand side. Also, the minus sign of the equation (1) is deleted, which I don't understand either.

Comment: I think your $\nabla$'s and $\Delta$'s are wrong. The first PDE in your question is subtracting a scalar and a vector and it should be $\Delta = \nabla\cdot\nabla$.

Comment: @whpowell96 Regarding $\nabla u-u=0$ since $u$ is acting upon a one-dimensional space, maybe I can say $\nabla u$ is the same as $\frac{du}{dx}$ right? Not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically starting with the equation:

$$-\Delta u = f$$

we multiply both sides by a test function $v$ to get

$$-v\Delta u = fv$$

and then we integrate over the domain $\Omega$

$$-\int_\Omega v\Delta u = \int_\Omega fv$$

and now we use integration by parts on the left hand side (there are regularity conditions on $u$ and $v$ to ensure you can do this)

$$\int_\Omega \nabla v \cdot \nabla u = -\int_\Omega v\Delta u$$

and now we recognize this as a bilinear form on the left hand side and a linear form on the right hand side.

#### How does integration by parts help?

The classical integration by parts formula is the following:
$$\int_a^b u'(x)v(x)dx = u(b)v(b)-u(a)v(a) - \int_a^bu(x)v'(x)dx$$
If we apply it to a second derivative, we get:
$$\int_a^b u''(x)v(x)dx = u'(b)v(b)-u'(a)v(a) - \int_a^bu'(x)v'(x)dx$$
Now, if $v(b)=v(a)=0$ then we have the one-dimensional version of what I wrote above
$$\int_\Omega \nabla v\cdot \nabla u = \int_\Omega fv$$
$$\int_a^b v'u' = -\int_a^b v u''$$
The fact that we take $v$ to be a test function means that it vanishes on the boundary of $\Omega$ (in the one-dimensional version, this means $v(a)=v(b)=0$ because the boundary is $\{a,b\}$).

To apply this to a PDE you just need the higher-dimensional version of integration by parts, i.e., [Green's first identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Green%27s_first_identity).

Comment: Thanks :) For some reason, I still don't understand how [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) helps with going from $-\int_\Omega v\Delta u = \int_\Omega fv$ to this equation $\int_\Omega \nabla v \cdot \nabla u = \int_\Omega fv$ I'm going to think about it...

Comment: I have added some commentary explaining this for a simple one-dimensional version of the problem in the paper.

Comment: It mostly makes sense now :) I just have one question. Where does this statement come from: `The fact that we take v to be a test function means that it vanishes on the boundary of Ω` Are there some references for studying. Thanks.

Comment: A [test function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) $f$ on a domain $\Omega$ is an infinitely differentiable function whose support (the set of points where it is nonzero, $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: f(x)\neq 0
\}$) has compact closure. Since $\Omega$ is an open set (this is an assumption we tend to make), any compact set contained in $\Omega$ must exclude the boundary of $\Omega$. Then, since the support is contained in a compact set, the support cannot contain any boundary points and so all test functions on $\Omega$ vanish on the boundary of $\Omega$.

Comment: Sorry, now I got it. The paper's equation (2) is actually asserting that $v = 0$ on the boundary $\Gamma$ so, it's an assumption.

Comment: No, it doesn't come from the boundary conditions of the problem; notice that we have $u'(a)$ and $u'(b)$ in the integration by parts formula, not $u(a)$ and $u(b)$. The test function $v$ we multiply by is arbitrary (so long as it is a test function). The vanishing on the boundary is really a consequence of being a test function (really, of having a compact support in $\Omega$). Basically, the compactness of the support means that the support must be *strictly* contained in $\Omega$ and so test functions must vanish on the boundary of $\Omega$ if it doesn't contain its boundary (open).

Comment: Your explanation is great. It's making more and more sense.

Comment: I [tried](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4867045/197913) the basis functions to solve the sample ODE by FEM. I used five basis functions from $\Psi_1$ to $\Psi_5$ . Domain of interest $\Omega$ is $ 0 \le x \le 1 $ and my boundary is $ x = 0 $. My first basis function $\Psi_1$ is not vanishing on the boundary of $\Omega$. Actually, it has to have a `1` value to satisfy the boundary condition. Now I'm confused about the assertion that all basis/test functions on Ω
must vanish on the boundary of Ω. By the way, fifth basis function $\Psi_5$ also won't vanish at $x = 1$. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Everything I wrote about test functions was for the problem with *homogeneous* boundary conditions that was described in the paper excerpt you included. For a problem with boundary conditions that aren't homogeneous, you need to "make" them homogeneous through some transformation - there are a lot of ways to do this. One way is to consider the solution $u$ to be of the form $v+h$ where $v$ solves a homogeneous problem and $h$ takes the boundary conditions into account.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

## Basis functions

I tried to solve the same ODE with the help of [basis functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_function) which are like basis vectors. They are nonzero only on a small portion inside the domain and zero at the rest.

In 2D, the basis function would look like this taken from [here](https://mfem.org/tutorial/fem/):

[image: 2D basis function]

So, in 1D, I created 5 piecewise basis functions like below to cover the domain of interest $\Omega$ i.e. $ 0\le x \le 1 $:

[image: 5 piecewise basis functions]

The general definition for a piecewise basis function is this:

$$ \Psi =  \left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
0 & \mbox{for} & x<x_0-\delta \\
\frac{1}{\delta}x-\frac{x_0-\delta}{\delta} & \mbox{for} & x_0 - \delta \leq x < x_0 \\
\frac{-1}{\delta}x+\frac{x_0+\delta}{\delta} & \mbox{for} & x_0 \leq x < x_0 + \delta \\
0 & \mbox{for} & x_0 + \delta \leq x
\end{array}\right. $$

I set $ \delta = 0.25 $ and $x_0 = 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0 $ for five basis functions $ \Psi_1, \Psi_2, \Psi_3, \Psi_4, \Psi_5 $

## Solving ODE

Then I set:

$$ u := \begin{bmatrix} \Psi_1 & \Psi_2 & \Psi_3 & \Psi_4 & \Psi_5 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix} $$

This $ u $ function satisfies the boundary condition. We have $ u = 1 \: \mathrm{on} \: \Gamma $ i.e. $ x = 0 $

$ \begin{bmatrix} dof \end{bmatrix} $ are the degrees of freedom i.e. unknowns:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \Psi \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \Psi_1 & \Psi_2 & \Psi_3 & \Psi_4 & \Psi_5 \end{bmatrix} \qquad \mbox{and} \qquad \begin{bmatrix} dof \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix} $$

Let's simply write:

$$ u := \begin{bmatrix} \Psi \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} dof \end{bmatrix} $$

Then the equation would be:

$$ \frac{du}{dx}-u=0 $$

$$ \frac{d}{dx}(\begin{bmatrix} \Psi \end{bmatrix}) \begin{bmatrix} dof \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} \Psi \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} dof \end{bmatrix} = 0 $$

Multiplied by the transpose of the basis functions:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \Psi \end{bmatrix} ^T \frac{d}{dx}(\begin{bmatrix} \Psi \end{bmatrix}) \begin{bmatrix} dof \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} \Psi \end{bmatrix} ^T \begin{bmatrix} \Psi \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} dof \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \Psi \end{bmatrix} ^T \; 0 $$

$$ (\begin{bmatrix} \Psi \end{bmatrix} ^T \frac{d}{dx}(\begin{bmatrix} \Psi \end{bmatrix}) - \begin{bmatrix} \Psi \end{bmatrix} ^T \begin{bmatrix} \Psi \end{bmatrix}) \; \begin{bmatrix} dof \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

Integrated over the domain of interest:

$$ \int_0^1 (\begin{bmatrix} \Psi \end{bmatrix} ^T \frac{d}{dx}(\begin{bmatrix} \Psi \end{bmatrix}) - \begin{bmatrix} \Psi \end{bmatrix} ^T \begin{bmatrix} \Psi \end{bmatrix}) dx \; \begin{bmatrix} dof \end{bmatrix} = \int_0^1 \begin{bmatrix} 0 \end{bmatrix} dx $$

Having integrated from `0` to `1`, the linear algebra would become:

$$ ( \begin{bmatrix} -0.5 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -0.5 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & -0.5 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & -0.5 & 0 & 0.5 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & -0.5 & 0.5 \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 0.083333 & 0.041667 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0.041667 & 0.166667 & 0.041667 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0.041667 & 0.166667 & 0.041667 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0.041667 & 0.166667 & 0.041667 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0.041667 & 0.083333 \end{bmatrix} ) \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

The final solution would be:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1.2418 \\ 1.6334 \\ 2.0616 \\ 2.6800 \end{bmatrix} $$

## Comparison

Comparison with the exact solution $e^x$ is done:

| x | $e^x$ | FEM approximation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0.1 | 1.10517 | 1.09673 |
| 0.2 | 1.2214 | 1.19345 |
| 0.3 | 1.34986 | 1.32013 |
| 0.4 | 1.49182 | 1.47676 |
| 0.5 | 1.64872 | 1.63339 |
| 0.6 | 1.82212 | 1.80466 |
| 0.7 | 2.01375 | 1.97593 |
| 0.8 | 2.22554 | 2.18526 |
| 0.9 | 2.4596 | 2.43265 |
| 1.0 | 2.71828 | 2.68004 |